# Setting width for different cells in a column

Tags: html, html-table, width, cells

I'm making a simple website, but is there a way to keep the width of different columns separate? What would I need to switch around or change?

```
<table>
<tr><td width="50%">Site logo</td>
<td width="50%">Navigation</td></tr>
<tr><td width="100%">Art Examples</td></tr>
<tr><td width="60%">News</td>
<td width="40%">About Me</td></tr>
<tr><td width="100%">Other websites</td></tr>
<tr><td width="100%">Copyright</td></tr>
</table>
```

I'm such a newbie to HTML and despite having a book right in front of me, I'm still confused about this part.

Comment: may or may not be of help, but you should really be using `<div>`s and css to layout your website...

Comment: I am using CSS, but I could find nothing to do with changing individual cells with CSS, only the entire table...

Answer (score 2):

You need a `colspan="2"` on the `<td>` tags where you only want one `<td>` per row.

Like this:

```
<table>
<tr><td width="50%">Site logo</td>
<td width="50%">Navigation</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2">Art Examples</td></tr>
<tr><td width="60%">News</td>
<td width="40%">About Me</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2">Other websites</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2">Copyright</td></tr>
</table>
```